# Writing web data to a TXT file

Tags: node.js, fs

(I want to use node-fetch not request)

I want to write data from a Web page (E.X google.com) to a TXT file (E.X google.txt) but it's not working. When I run the script then check my "google.txt" file all it says is `[object Object]`.

**Here is my code:**

```
const fs = require('fs');


request('https://google.com', function (error, body) {

    fs.writeFile('google.txt', body, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('Wrote google.com to google.txt !');
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you call `body` isn't really the HTTP response body, but the response object.  Rename it so that it's clear, and then use the `.body` property:

```
request('https://google.com', function (error, res) {

    fs.writeFile('google.txt', res.body, (err) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log('Wrote google.com to google.txt !');
    });

});
```

Comment: Great answer! Also, the reason why `google.txt` would only have `[object Object]` is because the argument passed into `fs.writeFile()` is indeed an objectt. You can bypass this by usually stringifying the argument you will pass like such: `fs.writeFile('google.txt', JSON.stringify(body))`, which will, as the answer above mentioned, write the whole stringified response object into that `.txt` file which is probably not what you would want.